# Date Time converter at csv file

Tags: bash

I have a csv file like this, that I'm editing in bash:

> SI ID;SI Status;Priorität;Kategorie betroffenes
>   Produkt;Komponente(n);Betroffene
>   Betriebsumgebung;Sicherheitsrelevanz;Datenschutzrelevanz;TI
>   Notfall;Zeit Erfassung;SI Melder;SI Bearbeiter;SI
>   Beschreibung;Aktualisiert;SI Zieltermin;SI Lösung;Meldungstyp
>   TTI-46;Gelöst;1;PDT02 TSP-X.509QES ;PDT02 TSP-X.509QES
>   ;TU;;;;13.Sep.17 11:56;CGMAG;CGMAG;Test;13.Sep.17 11:57;;Gelöst;SI
>   TTI-44;Gelöst;2;PDT03 TSP-X.509nonQES ;PDT03 TSP-X.509nonQES
>   ;;;;;12.Sep.17 15:51;dennis.rittmeier;dennis.rittmeier;OPBI00039942 -
>   Https-Verbindungen über SIS - zu langsam oder gar nicht
>   aufgebaut;15.Sep.17 7:53;;Gelöst;SI

What I want is to convert all date/times "bold" from this Format `15.Sep.17 15:53` to `2017-09-15T15:53:00+02`

Please can anybody help me?

Comment: Wait, is that all on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ d="12.Sep.17 15:51"
$ date -d "$(tr "." " " <<<"$d")" "+%FT%T%z"
2017-09-12T15:51:00-0400
```

I'm in the Canada Eastern time zone, hence the `-0400`

Comment: Hi,

thank you for the help!
`➤ grep -o ..\....\...\ ..:.. test.csv | while read line; do date -d "$(tr "." " " <<<"$line")" "+%FT%T%z"; echo "$line"; done
date: invalid date '13 Sep 17 11:56'
13.Sep.17 11:56
date: invalid date '13 Sep 17 11:57'
13.Sep.17 11:57
date: invalid date '12 Sep 17 15:51'
12.Sep.17 15:51
`
Why it call invalid date time?
When it write `➤ tr "." "."

`
the script interprete the date right but it's always say wrong date.
Need help... Sorry im bad at bash.
Thank you!

Comment: ok, on a different bash it works fine!
Thank you